# Debian10 python3 problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, debian-buster

I'm currently on Debian10:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
...
```

and many python3 modules seems not installed:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py", line 29, in <module>
    import csv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csv'
```

If I create a python file with:

```
import asyncio

print("hello")
```

and launch it, I have:

```
$ python3 toto.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toto.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
```

Any help is welcome to fix this mess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you need to reinstall some of your Python 3.7 packages; given that `concurrent.futures` is missing, I suspect you need at least

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libpython3.7-stdlib
```

This will also fix your `csv` and `cgi` problems.

Comment: Thank you really much ! That fixed everything !

Answer (score 0):

1. [install pip](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-debian-10/)
2. install library using `pip3 install ${PACKAGE_NAME}`

Comment: 1# `lsb_release -a` : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csv'`
2# `pip3 install csv` : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'`
3# `pip3 install cgi` : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/)
Generally pip is a key word which is used to install different required libraries.

Comment: Yes, but I can't install modules with pip/pip3 :
1# `lsb_release -a` : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csv'` 2# `pip3 install csv` : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'` 3# `pip3 install cgi` : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'`